# Crear un DataFrame a partir de otro filtarando columnas que contengan únicamente datos de un tipo

Tags: python, pandas

¿Cómo podría hacer para que a partir de un `df` que contiene datos de tipo objeto en algunas columnas y datos de tipo numéricos en otras, generar otro `df_number` que contenga solo las columnas que tienen datos de tipo numéricos y otro `df_object` que contenga a las columnas del tipo objeto?

Dentro de las columnas de tipo objeto, ¿Cómo podría separarlas entre las que contengan un tipo de respuesta, supongamos "Si" y "No" y aquellas que poseen otras como "Siempre", "Nunca", "Frecuentemente"?. Esto para posteriormente volver a generar otro DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para filtrar las columnas del DataFrame según el tipo de cada columna tienes a tu disposición el método [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html).

Vamos a partir de un ejemplo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> data = {"Col1": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            "Col2": (0.2, 4.5, 3.5, 7.1, 0.25),
            "Col3": ("Si", "No", "Si", "Si", "No"),
            "Col4": ("Siempre", "Nunca", "Siempre", "Frecuentemente", "Nunca")
           }

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   Col1  Col2 Col3            Col4
0     1  0.20   Si         Siempre
1     2  4.50   No           Nunca
2     3  3.50   Si         Siempre
3     4  7.10   Si  Frecuentemente
4     5  0.25   No           Nunca

>>> df.dtypes
Col1      int64
Col2    float64
Col3     object
Col4     object
Col5     object
dtype: object
```

Ahora podemos usar `df.select_dtypes`:

```
>>> df_number = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
>>> df_object = df.select_dtypes(include=[object])

>>> df_number
   Col1  Col2
0     1  0.20
1     2  4.50
2     3  3.50
3     4  7.10
4     5  0.25

>>> df_object
  Col3            Col4
0   Si         Siempre
1   No           Nunca
2   Si         Siempre
3   Si  Frecuentemente
4   No           Nunca
```

Para filtrar las columnas de tipo `str` según si contiene "Si"/"No", "Nunca"/"Siempre"/"Frecuentemente" puedes valerte de [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
>>> df_SiNo = df_object.loc[:, (df.isin({"Si", "No"})).all(axis=0)]

>>> df_SiNo
  Col3
0   Si
1   No
2   Si
3   Si
4   No
```

Sería conveniente normalizar las columnas primero si tienes casos como `[si, no, SI, No]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Voy a construir un dataframe que tenga un poco de todo, para usarlo de ejemplo.

```
import pandas as pd
n_filas = 100
sino = [random.choice(["Si", "No"]) for i in range(n_filas)]
siemprenunca = [random.choice(["Siempre", "Nunca", "Frecuentemente"]) for i in range(n_filas)]
unos = [1]*n_filas
ceros = [0]*n_filas
numeros = [random.random() for i in range(n_filas)]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    unos = unos,
    rand = numeros,
    de_acuerdo = sino,
    ceros = ceros,
    frecuencia = siemprenunca))

df.head().   # Veamos su aspecto
```

> [image: Dataframe]

Para separar las columnas por su tipo, puedes recorrerlas e ir acumulando en una lista las que sean de tipo objeto y en otra las que no:

```
numericas = []
objetos = []
for col in df.columns:
  if df[col].dtype == object:
    objetos.append(df[col])
  else:
    numericas.append(df[col])
```

Una vez las hemos separado en listas, mediante `pandas.concat()` podemos hacer con ellas un nuevo dataframe:

```
solonumeros = pd.concat(numericas, axis=1)
soloobjetos = pd.concat(objetos, axis=1)
```

```
solonumeros.head()
```

> [image: solonumeros]

```
soloobjetos.head()
```

> [image: soloobjetos]

Dentro de esta última puedes separar las columnas de tipo si/no mediante un mecanismo como este:

```
sino = []
for col in soloobjetos.columns:
  if set(df[col].values) == set(("Si", "No")):
    sino.append(df[col])

pd.concat(sino, axis=1).head()
```

> [image: si-no]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!